# foreign key assignment for child object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a very simple question which I am not able to get my head around. I have following models

```
class Parent(models.Model):   
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Child(models.Model):
      boardid = models.ForeignKey(Parent,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="child")
      id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Serializers

```
class ParentSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('__all__')

class ChildSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = Child
       fields = ('id','title')
```

and simple createAPIview for the children

```
class ChildCreateView(CreateAPIView):
      queryset= Child.objects.all()
      serializer_class = ChildSerializer
```

When I call this url 
                    /api/parent/1/child/create 
  I want to pre populate the foreign key board id with the id 1 and create child object with rest of the information which I will be providing in the body . How is this possible to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Initially, add **`boardid`** field to the **`ChildSerializer`**,

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = '__all__' # no need of "()"


class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'boardid')
```

Then, use the below json payload to create the instance.

```
{
    "title":"child title",
    "boardid":123,
    ... other data
}
```

Comment: Thanks. my question is a bit unclear. I dont want to pass the boardid in body. when i call this api  /api/parent/1/child/create to create child , i want the child to be created for parent with id 1